# Windows 10 Storage app is misreporting used space?

Tags: windows-10, storage

According to the Windows 10 Storage App I have 11.5 GB in Temporary Files, but when examining the Temporary Files node there it only lists 58.4 MB. Is this a bug in the app? Or does it look in different locations for the high level node compared to the detail view? and if so, which additional locations does it look in?

[image: C Drive overview]
[image: Examining the Temporary Files node]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two folders for temporary files :

- The `C:\Windows\Temp` directory is a system folder and is used by Windows to store temporary files.
- The `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\` directory which is separate for each user
  and is used by third party programs to store their temporary files.

You may override these by setting the environmental variables of TEMP and TMP,
of which there are two versions : For the current user and for the general case.

For more information see the Microsoft article
[Why are there both TMP and TEMP environment variables, and which one is right?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150417-00/?p=44213)